# Using regex to replace one number with another of same size in a text file

Tags: python, regex

I have a text file with 100 lines. On each line, there is a number with format `nnn.nn`.

I have another number `NNN.NN`. Using Python, I want to replace `nnn.nn` on each line with `NNN.NN`. But `nnn.nn` is located at a different place in the line each time.

I am currently reading in the whole file by:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    my_file = f.readlines()
```

and I know that I can find the relevant number by doing:

```
re.findall(r' \d\d\d.\d\d ',my_file[line_index])[0]
```

but I'm not sure how to tell my code to replace that number (wherever it is) with my new number.

Comment: *replace nnn.nn on each line with NNN.NN* - and how do you distinguish `nnn.nn` from `NNN.NN` in terms of **numbers**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would be, also with re:

```py
import re

x="23.320 ododkowe 23.565 odef0oi04 30.403 320"

re.sub(r"\d\d.\d\d\d ", "xx.xxx ", x)
```

output:

```
'xx.xxx ododkowe xx.xxx odef0oi04 xx.xxx 320'
```